# I don't understand how to fetch data from API in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, fetch

I want to get the video title and video id from this api https://invidio.us/api/v1/search?q=

as an example you search https://invidio.us/api/v1/search?q=tech+lead

and you get this json.

```
[
  {
    "type": "video",
    "title": "\"The Last Programmer\" (hacking the pandemic)",
    "videoId": "heXI1pgQhvY",
    "author": "TechLead",
    "authorId": "UC4xKdmAXFh4ACyhpiQ_3qBw",
    "authorUrl": "/channel/UC4xKdmAXFh4ACyhpiQ_3qBw",
    "videoThumbnails": [...],
    "description": "Ex-Google TechLead hacks into the viral pandemic.  Check out http://coderpro.com/ for 100+ coding interview videos explained ...",
    "descriptionHtml": "<div class=\"yt-lockup-description yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2\" dir=\"ltr\">Ex-Google TechLead hacks into the viral pandemic.  Check out <a href=\"http://coderpro.com/\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"http://coderpro.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\" dir=\"ltr\" class=\"yt-uix-redirect-link\">http://coderpro.com/</a> for 100+ coding interview videos explained ...</div>",
    "viewCount": 58578,
    "published": 1585252516,
    "publishedText": "1 day ago",
    "lengthSeconds": 447,
    "liveNow": false,
    "paid": false,
    "premium": false
  },
{...},  //other videos.
{...},
...]
```

My goal is to write a program in dart/Flutter that will take each video title and its corresponding videoId and push them to a list.

I've tried searching online on how to do this and I've come across https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

But it seem way complex for what I want to do. I want to know if a much more simpler way exists. Considering also that I only need at most the first 8 videos from the search query.

Comment: Fetching data in Flutter using HTTP is the same as in many other languages / environments. So, no, there isn't a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are saying you don't want to create a class because you don't need it. You can get away with not creating one, even though it can be a bit more error prone:

```dart
final result = await http.get('https://invidio.us/api/v1/search?q=tech+lead');
final data = json.decode(result.body);
data.forEach((e) {
  print(e['title']);
  print(e['videoId']);
});
```